# Can I multiply the real parts of two complex matrices using dgemm?

Tags: c, cython, blas

I have two complex matrices A and B, with matching shapes.

Is there a way to cleverly setup the dgemm arguments so as to get the result of the matrix multiplications of the real parts of these matrices only?

Intuitively, the real and imaginary parts of a complex matrix are stored in an interlaced way, so I guess they correspond to strided real arrays.

Note: I am using cython and accessing blas via `scipy.linalg.cython_blas`, but any pure C solution is welcome as well.

Comment: You may need to copy over the real part to new matrices, but that is O(n^2) whereas matrix multiplication is O(n^3) (for square matrices), so for large matrices the overhead is probably not that huge, though it will of course require more memory.

Comment: I think I managed to do what I want using BLIS, and their "general strides" cf https://github.com/flame/blis/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#im-used-to-thinking-in-terms-of-column-majorrow-major-storage-and-leading-dimensions-what-is-a-row-stride--column-stride But I'd rather use a more standard BLAS

Comment: @SimonGoater that's exactly what I want to avoid though ...

Comment: Yes, I understood what you're trying to do. If you don't need the matrices afterwards, you could just set the imaginary parts to zero as an O(n^2) operation, then multiply them as complex matrices. If you solve it with BLIS, I suggest you post an answer which may help others.

Comment: Interesting, but this is missing the bigger picture, which I didn't explain. What I actually want to compute is the real part only of the multiplication of two complex matrices. But this is merely A.real x B.real - A.imag x B.imag, hence my question. As to BLIS, I'm curretly measuring the performance but I expect a drop on my particular hardware

Comment: You should re-word your question then. It sounds like you want Re(A) * Re(B), not Re(A*B).

Comment: Also, it would be interesting if you posted your benchmarks of complex A*B vs copying to new matrices and calculating real A.real x B.real - A.imag x B.imag.It should be about half the operations, so may be significantly faster, though matrix multiplication is notoriously memory bound in general, so it might not make much difference in practice, or could even be slower.

Comment: "You should re-word your question then. It sounds like you want Re(A) * Re(B), not Re(A*B)." ==> I maintain what I said. Re(A) * Re(B) is but a means to an end.

Comment: BLAS (including cblas) `dgemm` / `sgemm` / `cgemm` / `zgemm` does not have an option for strided matrices.  In SciPy, however, you can get the real part of an `ndarray` as `array.real`, and the imaginary part as `array.imag`.  You can use these to compute your result, or the former to extract your wanted result from the result of the complex multiplication.  I am uncertain whether `real` and `imag` make copies of the arrays to which they are applied, however.

Comment: FYI, I managed to rephrase my original problem so that I need to compute Re(A\*B^H) instead of Re(A\*B) (where ^H denotes the conjugate transpose). This operation can actually be treated with a single call to real gemm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I think this is impossible using standard BLAS, but I was able to do this using BLIS. Here is an example in Cython:

```
cimport blis.cy
from libc.stdlib cimport abort, malloc, free

# Computes the real part of a @ b
cpdef void blis_matmul_real(
    double complex[:,::1] a ,
    double complex[:,::1] b ,
    double[:,::1] c         ,
) noexcept nogil:

    cdef int m = a.shape[0]
    cdef int k = a.shape[1]
    cdef int n = b.shape[1]

    cdef double* a_real = <double*> &a[0,0]
    cdef double* b_real = <double*> &b[0,0]
    cdef double* res = &c[0,0]

    cdef int lda = 2 * k
    cdef int ldb = 2 * n

    blis.cy.gemm(
        blis.cy.NO_TRANSPOSE, blis.cy.NO_TRANSPOSE,
        m, n, k,
        1.0, a_real, lda, 2,
        b_real, ldb, 2 ,
        0.0, res, n, 1
    )

    # Pointer addition
    a_real += 1
    b_real += 1

    blis.cy.gemm(
        blis.cy.NO_TRANSPOSE, blis.cy.NO_TRANSPOSE,
        m, n, k,
        -1.0, a_real, lda, 2,
        b_real, ldb, 2 ,
        1.0, res, n, 1
    )
```